# Partition to be used for dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

While dual boot...

Is it mandatory to shrink C partition and install Ubuntu in the unallocated free space....

Or

Can I install Ubuntu on D partition

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product details (different ISO/products have different installers), but if you don't want an option that is offered; use the "*Manual Partitioning*" or "*Something else*" option to setup whatever you prefer.

Comment: There are no drive letters in Ubuntu. If C is the first drive, the boot drive. It is easiest in dual boot to have Ubuntu there. That way the installer will see that Windows is installed and ask you to install beside. It will make a Grub that lets you choose the OS on machine start up.

Comment: If C is the only drive/partition on your computer and windows takes all the space, only then do need to shrink Windows to make space or get another drive.  Other wise you can use/make any free space(if big enough) on any drive/partition on your computer.  Back up important data first, in case of oops, we all have them.

Comment: If you have nothing in your "D" partition, you can delete that partition and make that space unallocated and free for Ubuntu installation. Ubuntu uses a different partition format called `ext4` so it cannot use the Windows D partition as is.

Answer (score 0):

It's your computer, so you're free to install Ubuntu on either unallocated disk space or on any partition or even use the built-in GParted partition editor in the *Try Ubuntu* option of the Ubuntu installer to merge unallocated disk space with a partition or partitions that you no longer need.

It's important to check any partition before you use it for something else that it doesn't contain another OS that you want to keep, like Windows, or if it is a data partition that all the data on it has been backed up somewhere else, for example to an external hard drive.